# Set the value of a form from the controller

Tags: ember.js

I have `categories` which have many `products` and a form which displays drop-down menus of both. Once a `Category` gets picked the values of the `Product` drop-down get filtered so that only `products` which belong to the `category` get displayed. That works fine until the user sets the `selectedProduct` drop-down to a specific value.

*How can I reset the `selectedProduct` drop-down to `All Products` if the user clicks on a different `Category` after he clicked on a `Product`?*

**app/templates/index.hbs**

```
{{view "select" prompt="All Categories"
                content=filteredCategories
                optionLabelPath="content.name"
                optionValuePath="content.name"
                value=selectedCategory}}

{{view "select" prompt="All Products"
                content=filteredProducts
                optionLabelPath="content.name"
                optionValuePath="content.name"
                value=selectedProduct}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your observer for `selectedCategory` in your index controller, you need to have a conditional to see if a `selectedProduct` already exists. If it does, then set `filteredProducts` to all products and `selectedProduct` to '':

```
if (this.get('selectedProduct')) {
  this.set('filteredProducts', [<array of all products>]) && this.set('selectedProduct', '');
}
```

However, I am a bit confused as to why you want to set it to an array of all the products when a new category is picked..wouldn't you want to set `filteredProducts` to an array of products based on what the new category is?